# app.UseExceptionHandler("Home/Error") not going to Home/Error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I created a simple Home/Error page that I can go to directly with no problem.  It just returns some static HTML for now.   When I change Startup.cs to this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {

            app.UseBrowserLink();
            //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I would expect to get redirected to Home/Error.  Instead I am getting a blank screen and if I look at the "Network" tab in Chrome Developer tools, I see a 500 Status returned from my "Home/TestException" action which throws an exception.

If I switch it to app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(), that page comes up just fine.  Any ideas why this is not working?

I am using .Net Core 1.0.0-rc1-update1.

Here are "dependencies" from Project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "AutoMapper": "4.2.1",
  "Dapper": "1.42.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "2.2.1",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
  "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess": "12.1.24160419",
  "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0"
},
```

Comment: I cannot duplicate this issue.  Please post your entire Configure() method and what version of ASP.NET Core you are using.

Comment: Thanks Clint, I edited my post above with this information.

Comment: Is your application throwing any exception? This will be executed only if your application is running in  `Hosting:Environment Development` and throws exception.

Simple way to see this, from your `project.json` remove line `"preserveCompilationContext": true` and see `/Home/Error/` will work.

Comment: Can you share your home controller & View directory structure?

Comment: What exception you see if you switch to `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` ?

Comment: Hi Avi - If I change the code to app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() it displays the expected exception page just fine.  I can go directly to Home/Error and get my static message just fine as well.   I have a Home/TestException which throws an exception.  It may be some version issue of the software.  If I set a breakpoint in Home/Error controller method, it never hits it when I throw the exception.

Comment: If it's any help, I'm using core 1.0.0-rc2-3002702 and it works as expected. Not sure if you're in a situation where you can update easily though. Probably should regardless, though.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyFun, that indeed ended up being the answer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did not work under rc1.  It wasn't until I moved the entire project to RC2 that this all started working.  I think could have just been a versioning issue with some of the versions of the dnx components (which are now obsolete).   Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

**app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute** seems to work well:

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
 {
     app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
     app.UseBrowserLink();
 }
 else
 {
     app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect to get redirected to Home/Error. Instead I am getting a blank screen and if I look at the "Network" tab in Chrome Developer tools, I see a 500 Status returned from my "Home/TestException" action which throws an exception.
>
> If I switch it to app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(), that page comes up just fine. Any ideas why this is not working?

I'm not sure why `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");` not working - maybe it's depends form exception kind? - can you give us example of your exception?

As the temporary (or not) solution you can also use additionally: `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Code/{0}");`

this give you redirection to `Error` page in your case too, and `{0}` it's error code - you can delete it form address or you can use it on error page.

More information:
[MVC Core Error Handling](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/error-handling.html#asp-net-mvc-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when trying to use a "Razor **page**", as opposed to a "Razor **view**", to do error handling. The problems was that none of the "Razor pages" were working because routing for Razor pages was not set up.

I fixed it by adding .MapRazorPages() to my routing

```
app.UseEndpoints(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.MapControllerRoute("Fallback",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
                    );

                cfg.MapRazorPages();
            });
```